# Friedman Test with repetitions

Tags: repeated-measures

I want to use the Friedman test to evaluate the milk production on different races, but we have ten animals of each race. Can we use the mean of the ten animals of each race to conduct the Friedman test?

Comment: How do repeated measures come into this situation? Do you have repeated measures on each animal? By "race", do you mean *species*?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but what you are wanting to do is called the Kruskal-Wallis (KW) test or the Nonparametric Rank $F$ test.  Any elementary statistics textbook with ANOVA coverage should have this described.  In this test, all observations are ranked from $1$ to $n$ in ascending order.  Then you calculated the typical $F$ test statistic, only you use the mean ranks within each of the races and overall means of ranks to calculate the $F$ statistic.